# Stop mysql auto_increment_increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

After stopping MASTER-MASTER replication, I tried to stop auto_increment_increment in my.cnf. The change registered. Now when I run **SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';**

```
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 1     |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
```

But when a new row is added to the table the id still increments by 2.

Comment: Did you restart the MySQL Server after making those changes in my.cnf?

Comment: Yes I did. I imagine if I didn't, auto_increment_increment would still be set to 2.